# Regex problem, matches the whole string instead of a part

Tags: c#, regex

I have this string:

> (3 + 5) * (1 + 1)

I want to match this strings:

> (3 + 5)

and

> (1 + 1)

I used this to try to match it:

```
(\(.*\))
```

But that matches the whole string, from the first ( to the last ).

Any idea on how to fix this / make it working?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898210/greedy-non-greedy-all-greedy-matching-in-c-regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't care about nested parenthesis, use

```
(\([^()]*\))
#  ^^^^^
```

to avoid matching any `(` or `)` inside a group.

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways to look at this:

- Instead of greedy repetition `*`, I want reluctant `*?`

  - i.e. `(\(.*?\))`
- Instead of `.`, I want `[^)]`, i.e. anything but `)`

  - i.e. `(\([^)]*\))`

Note that neither handles nested parentheses well. Most regex engine would have a hard time handling arbitrarily nested parantheses, but in .NET you can use [balancing groups definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx#balancing_group_definition).

#### Related questions

- [Difference between `.*?` and `.*` for regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075130/difference-between-and-for-regex)
- [How can I exclude some characters from a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548949/how-can-i-exclude-some-characters-from-a-class)

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) and [Repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use a non-greedy match, ie

```
(\(.*?\))
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
([^*]+)
```

Comment: A bit too specific to the example -- it won't work in more general cases, where the thing separating the groups of parentheses might not be `*`.