# Unexpected Regex Result Occured

Tags: c#, regex

The following code segment gives me unexpected results. But, I'd like to take right result.

Code syntax:

string parametersText = "\"parameter1\", \"parameter2\", \"parameter3\"";

```
    string findPattern = "(?<=\").*?(?=\"(, |$))";
    MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(parametersText, findPattern);
```

The result:

```
parameter1
, "parameter2
, "parameter3
```

But I'd like to get as following:

```
parameter1
parameter2
parameter3
```

How Can I Acheve this?

Any helps would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lookarounds do not consume characters and as such, it starts matching on the next `\"` and ends specifically on the next `\"(, |$)`.

Try adding the `(, |$)` in the lookbehind as well:

```
(?<=(?:, |^)\").*?(?=\"(?:, |$))
```

I converted the capture groups into non-capture groups btw.

[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/SP4sJU)

Comment: Oh and forgot to mention that the `$` of course should be converted to `^` :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Regex?

```
string parametersText = "\"parameter1\", \"parameter2\", \"parameter3\"";

parametersText.Split(',').Select(a => a.Replace("\"", "").Trim());
```

Or as per suggestions

```
parametersText.Split(new[] { ", " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(a => a.Trim('"', ' '));
```

Comment: But, what if a comma ',' comes inside parameters?

Comment: or `text.Split(", ").Select(x=>x.Trim(new []{'\\', '"'}))`

Comment: I'd like to use regex, without regex, I can find solution. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: then `parametersText.Split(new [] {"\\\""}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(x=>x.Trim()).Where(x=>x != ",")`

Answer (score 0):

`.*` is *greedy* and will match as many characters as possible, thus including `, "` where possible. You can read up on the topic here: [Greedy, Non-Greedy, All-Greedy Matching in C# Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898210/greedy-non-greedy-all-greedy-matching-in-c-sharp-regex)